# Send large file to backend only when user click on upload button

Tags: javascript, file, file-upload

i want to upload a large file. First when user click on choose file he should be able to choose file and file name should be displayed.when he clicks on upload button then only this file should be send to server.

```
<div>
    <input type="file" />
    <button onclick="uploadFileToServer()">uploadFileToServer</button>
</div>
```

**Note** : I have 1GB file. so before sending it to server , i have to slice and send chunk (i am able to slice file into small chunks).

Answer (score 0):

Take the invocation operator '()' off of you onClick= assignment. This is causing your function to execute when defined rather than when clicked.